# Error: Cannot find module 'ejs' after I build my Node app with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am trying to compile my node/express app using webpack 4.

Development server(transpiled in realtime using babel) works great, but after I build the server with webpack I get an error:

`{ Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'
    at i (/home/ray/projects/screenplays/server/dist/server.build.js:2121:331)
... }`

(there are no build errors, and server launches fine, error happens after I try to load a page)

All the modules are installed. My webpack config is [here](https://github.com/raymestalez/screenplays/blob/master/server/webpack.server.js).

I am building it using:

`webpack --mode production --config ./webpack.server.js --progress`

And running it using:

`NODE_ENV=production node ./index.js`

[index.js](https://github.com/raymestalez/screenplays/blob/master/server/index.js)  just loads the compiled file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    /* In production, serve the webpacked server file. */
    console.log('Production mode, running ./dist/server.build.js')
    require('./dist/server.build.js')
}
```

I've been trying to figure it out for a long time, nothing seems to work. The whole project is [here](https://github.com/raymestalez/screenplays).

Any advice?